# Narrow to wide data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a following Data frame (df) as shown below:

[image: df]

Is it possible to reshape my (df) into (df1) as shown below:

[image: df1]

I have provided a sample of my code, but it does not work.

Appreciate any through or suggestion here.

Many Thanks

The sample of my code here:

```
data = {'Source': ['Rainfall', 'Inflow', 'SWCD', 'SWCD','Rainfall','Inflow', 'SP1', 'SP1'],
        'Target': ['SWCD', 'SWCD', 'Evp', 'Outflow','SP1','SP1', 'Evp', 'Overflow']}  
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df.loc[:, ["Source", "Target"]]
df1 = df.values.flatten()
df.set_index('Target').T
```

Comment: You expectations are a bit unclear. Check maybe that: ```df.set_index('Target').T ```

Comment: Hi PawelWL, 

Yeah, it is bit tricky to achieve my expectation, but your suggestion (df.set_index('Target').T) is closed to what i was hoping for.

is it possible to move and replace "Evp" and "outflow" from target row with "SWCD" at source row?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another, generic, option without a loop:

```
vals = ['SWCD', 'SP1']

tmp = (df.mask(df['Target'].isin(vals))
         .fillna(df.rename(columns={'Target': 'Source', 'Source': 'Target'}))
       )
# or, if you only have Source/Target
# tmp = (df.mask(df['Target'].isin(vals))
#          .fillna(df.set_axis(['Target', 'Source'], axis=1))
#        )

out = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(tmp))
```

Output (as image as it's only a MultiIndex):

[image]

Alternative output:

```
tmp.set_index('Source').T
```

Output:

```
Source      SWCD    SWCD SWCD     SWCD       SP1     SP1  SP1       SP1
Target  Rainfall  Inflow  Evp  Outflow  Rainfall  Inflow  Evp  Overflow
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something that might help

```py
# First you need to swap the columns values for columns provided in a list
for col in ['SWCD', 'SP1']:
    mask = df['Target'] == col
    df.loc[mask, ['Source', 'Target']] = (df.loc[mask, ['Target', 'Source']].values)

# Then set index and transpose
df1 =  df.set_index('Source').T
```

Comment: Ahh thank alots. That is what I am looking for. One last question is that possible to loop all elements I have the source column. For example, set i = SP1, SWCD, SP2, SP3...etc. But your solution is great, and I am thankful for that. :)

Comment: I am not sure I understad fully what you need. You need to precisely know when you want to swap the columns. In the solution I just put 'SWCD' and 'SP1' in the list and when the loop finds elements from this list in the 'Target' column the rows will be swapped. You can extend the list with other elements. Good luck! :)